# Advice on getting started in web design and web applications?

Tags: php

I am an experienced programmer, and I have a few little ideas that I think would work really well as PHP based web applications. I have no problem with learning PHP, mySQL, etc, but I do have a problem with the design of a webpage in itself.

I am used to interface design ala Interface Builder and Swing, where there are some clearly defined classes with clearly defined behaviors etc. To me, web design is the wild west where I have to write my entire user interface, complete with little effects and stuff, on my own.

I'm not afraid of this by any means, I just need some advice on where to start. I've like to learn some proper HTML for starters, since everything I know how to do is static and ugly, and I'd like to learn Javascript to be able to make my pages more elegant as time goes by.

In short, I'd like it if someone gave me a few books or suggestions on how to make the programming that I know and love more visible and accessible to internet users.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of books that I'd recommend for learning a couple of these:

[Sams Teach Yourself Web Publishing with HTML and CSS in One Hour a Day](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328860)

[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

[HTML & XHTML Pocket Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805861)

[Designing Web Interfaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516258)

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596145) is my go-to book for any css/html problems I may have.  It works in detail through common elements you may have to create, such as: forms, tables, general layouts etc and suggests solutions based upon standards compliant CSS/HTML.

For JavaScript check out [JavaScript with DOM Scripting and AJAX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596803).

Note: As soon as you're comfortable with JavaScript it's worth looking at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) or one of the other many JavaScript libraries that take away the headache of cross-browser compatibility.